# Why is map.get with 2 parameters possible?

Tags: scala

I have 2 maps, `map1` and `map2`, both of type `Map[String, MyType]`.

What I wanted to do was, searching for a key in the first map, if not found, search in the second one, and if still not found, use a default value:

`map1.getOrElse(name, map2.getOrElse(name, defVal))`

However, what I accidently wrote was:

`map1.getOrElse(name, map2.get(name, defVal))`.

Surprisingly, this didn't cause a compile-time error (and returned `null`), although i called `get` with 2 parameters.

As I can see in the IDE (Eclipse), it calls `get(x$1 : Any) : MyType` of `java.util.Map`, instead of `get(key : String) : Option[MyType]` of `scala.collection.MapLike`

Why doesn't it report an error, when I call `map2.get` with a second parameter? As far as I can see in the documentation, `map.get` only takes one parameter? Does it interpret the two parameters as a tuple or something similar (and use this tuple as `Any`-parameter)?

If relevant, `MyType` is a class from a referenced `Java`-project.

I am quiet new in Scala, so if this is trivial or a basic concept that I missed (and everyone programming scala should already know), please tell me what to search for.

**EDIT:**

As I saw in the comments, that the problem is not reproduceable, I saw, that I hava `import scala.collection.javaConversions._`, because I get the collections from a Java-Project that I reference. Now it is also reproducable with a short code like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
object Main {
  def main (args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val map1 = Map("1" -> 2)
    val map2 = Map("2" -> 1)
    map1.getOrElse("1", map2.get("2", 0))
  }
}
```

Comment: The scenario does not seem to be reproducible on my end. The compiler will not agree with this.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I don't know if you saw my edit in April. Now it is reproducable. Do you agree with Reactormonk 's answer, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be argument adaptation from `map2.get(name, defVal)` to `map2.get((name, defVal))`.

Edit: Use `JavaConverters`. `JavaConversions` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I am not sure how you made this work, it should not be possible.

It is still not doable ( at least with Scala 2.12.1)

```
scala> val map1 = Map("1" -> "!", "2" -> "@")
map1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> !, 2 -> @)

scala> val map2 = Map("3" -> "#", "4" -> "$")
map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(3 -> #, 4 -> $)

scala> val s = map1.getOrElse("3", map2.get("3", "%"))
<console>:13: error: too many arguments (2) for method get: (key: String)Option[String]
       val s = map1.getOrElse("3", map2.get("3", "%"))
                                                 ^
```

Comment: As menitioned in the edit-section of the question, it works (at least in my IDE) if you do the import of scala.collection.JavaConversions._ You can try my example, it compiles and runs.

Comment: True. `JavaConversions` have been deprecated just because issues like this where they break the expected behaviour.